# Lock and do all work, or release and grab only when necessary?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Which of these two alternatives is the better one?

Locking outside the loops?

```
lock (_workLock)
{
    foreach (var resultObject in getObjectTask.Result)
    {
        foreach (var key in resultObject.Keys)
        {
            string value = resultObject.GetValue(key);
            _lockedObject.DoSomething(key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

or locking only when the locked object is accessed?

```
foreach (var resultObject in getObjectTask.Result)
{
    foreach (var key in resultObject.Keys)
    {
        string value = resultObject.GetValue(key);
        lock (_workLock)
            _lockedObject.DoSomething(key, value);
    }
}
```

There can potentially be 5-10 simultaneous operations wanting to do this roughly at the same time. Here's the surrounding code:

```
var tasks =
    from provider in _objectProviders
    select Task.Factory.StartNew(() => provider.Objects)
        .ContinueWith(getObjectTask =>
        {
            // One of the operation bodies from above would go here
        });

var taskList = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
taskList.Wait();

// Use results from operations here
```

EDIT: This isn't really an answer, so I'm not posting it as an answer, but after the input in the comment section, I refactored my code as such, and now I no longer need a lock at all:

```
var tasks =
    (from provider in _objectProviders
    select Task.Factory.StartNew(() => provider.Objects)).ToList();

while (tasks.Count > 0)
{
    int completedTask = Task.WaitAny(tasks.ToArray<Task>());
    var task = tasks[completedTask];
    var objects = task.Result;

    foreach (var resultObject in objects)
    {
        foreach (var key in resultObject.Keys)
        {
            string value = resultObject.GetValue(key);
            _unlockedObject.DoSomething(key, value);
        }
    }

    tasks.RemoveAt(completedTask);
}
```

Comment: Forgive me if I am missing something but if you lock around the entire operation then won't it defeat the object of doing it on sepperate threads because only one thread can ever be doing anything at once.  You might as well do it synchronously.

Comment: Is there a chance that `getObjectTask.Result` collection or `resultObject.Keys` collection can change while you're looping? What is the type of `getObjectTask.Result` and `resultObject.Keys` ?

Comment: The general rule is to only lock when necessary and release as soon as the lock is no longer needed. Otherwise, you're making others wait unnecessarily.

Comment: @BenRobinson - The hard work is all done in the `provider.Objects` call. `_lockedObject` can only handle a single entry at a time, BUT it's faster to start passing things onto `_lockedObject` as soon as one of the `provider.Objects` calls is done, rather than waiting until they are all done. Hence why I ContinueWith(). @SriramSakthivel - No, the result objects are unchanging once returned. @JaimeStill - I don't see where you're locking in your example...

Comment: Hm, maybe a better solution would be to Wait() on the `provider.Objects` tasks and handle them one by one that way until they're all done. Is that what you're suggesting, @BenRobinson?

Comment: @Alex yes I think that makes more sense and give you more readable, maintainable code.

Comment: @BenRobinson Not sure whether you noticed it, but I made an edit to my question to show how I am doing it now. It sure feels better. The locking I was doing felt wrong after you pointed out how I'm locking the whole operation anyway.

Comment: A lock in one place is not usually very useful. There must be other places you lock `_workLock`. For example when adding work to `getObjectTask.Result` Without seeing the whole story, hard to understand what the lock is for and what is best.

Answer (score 1):

### It Depends!

Which one is better is 100% dependent on what your task is doing.

Grabbing the lock inside the loop means you waste a ton of time acquiring and releasing the lock.  However, if most of your time is spent doing non-locked parallel things, it could free up the lock enough to get more parallelism.

Grabbing the lock at the top of the loop prevents parallelism, but saves on locking, which can be expensive compared to your operation.

All you can do it look at your profiler and find out which one is best in your situation.  For reference, locks on modern hardware take about 100-150 operations to lock/unlock if there is no contention (that's a rough rule of thumb, not a hard set value).

Consider a third option which is a hybrid of the two: do all of your parallel operations, and batch up the serial operations.  Perhaps every 10 objects, grab the lock and quickly do all of the serial work.  This lets you get the best of both worlds